# How can I get Weblogic to connect to a RedBrick database?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, weblogic, driver, redbrick

I am trying to get Weblogic 9.2.3 to talk to a legacy RedBrick database and am having trouble.  I have the redbrick.jar file from the software installation and have added to my APP_RUNTIME_CLASSPATH and my MANIFEST_CLASSPATH.  This is my jConnect template line:

```
<url>jdbc:rbw:protocol:${DB_LT_SERVER}:${DB_LT_PORT}/${DB_LT_NAME}</url>
<driver-name>redbrick.jdbc.RBWDriver</driver-name>
```

(Variables get replaced with good values during build.)

When starting up I get this error:

```
weblogic.common.ResourceException: Unknown Data Source jConnectLT

weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourceSystemException: Cannot load driver class: redbrick.jdbc.RBWDriver
```

Do I have to do more to make Weblogic see the RedBrick database?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you not fool yourself by modifying any CLASSPATH variable.

The redbrick JDBC driver JAR belongs in the /server/lib of your WebLogic server.  I believe the bootstrap class loader for the server should be able to find it that way.

The exception says that the JAR is not in your CLASSPATH, even though you think it is.

UPDATE: I may have chosen the wrong directory.  [These docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/jdbc_admin/third_party_drivers.html) say you should create a redbrick directory under server/ext/jdbc.

Comment: Well, I had high hopes for this, but I put the redbrick.jar file in the wlserver9.2.3/server/lib directory and got the same failure.

Comment: Check the WebLogic docs and see if there's another step that I missed.  That's the idea, anyway.

Comment: See new info.  I think reading those docs carefully will sort you out.

Answer (score 0):

Put your RedBrick JDBC driver anywhere you want (I usually place them in `WL_HOME\server\lib`) and add it (you **have to**) to the domain `CLASSPATH` in `setDomainEnv.sh`/`setDomainEnv.cmd` (in WebLogic domain `bin` folder).